# Combine two queries into one query Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I need to combine two queries into one so i can call it one time on my foreach inside a table in my blade view. I tried using `merge()` but it displays two separate queries. `CountofPatents` are all the patents that were submitted by a user and `CountofApprovedPatents` are the patents which has the `status` of "2".  Here's how it looks now:

> array 0 [person_id : 1
>   CountofApprovedPatents: 4
>   status: 2]
>
> array 1 [person_id : 2
>   CountofApprovedPatents: 2
>   status: 2]
>
> array 2 [person_id : 1
>   CountofPatents: 5]
>
> array 3 [person_id : 2
>   CountofPatents: 4]

Here's how it's supposed to look like

> array 0 [person_id : 1
>   CountofApprovedPatents: 4
>   CountofPatents: 5]
>
> array 1 [person_id : 2
>   CountofApprovedPatents: 2
>   CountofPatents: 4]

Here's my code so far

AdminController

```
$start = $request->input('start');
$end = $request->input('end');
$approvedPatents = DB::table('patents')
->select('person_id', DB::raw('count(*) as CountofApprovedPatents'))
->where([
    ['status', '=', 2],
    ['date_approved', '>=', $start],
    ['date_approved', '<=', $end],
])
->groupBy('person_id')
->orderBy('status', 'desc')
->get();

$totalPatents = DB::table('patents')
->select('person_id', DB::raw('count(*) as CountofPatents'))
->where([
    ['date_approved', '>=', $start],
    ['date_approved', '<=', $end],
])
->groupBy('person_id')
->orderBy('status', 'desc')
->get();  

$patents = $approvedPatents->merge($totalPatents);
$results = $patents->all();  
return view('admin.patents.showPatents', compact('results', 
'start', 'end'));
```

Is it possible to combine these two queries?

```
$results = DB::table('patents')
    ->union($approvedPatents)
    ->union($totalPatents)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Doesn't your first query have 3 columns ? Where did `status` go?

Comment: My bad, edited my post.

Comment: If you join these 2 queries, should `status = 2` apply to all rows?

Comment: No it only applies with the `CountofApprovedPatents` , because the other query disregards the status value. `CountofPatents` counts all associated with the `person_id` whether the `status` is 1 or 2.

Comment: So how would expected output look like after joining them since `status = 2` doesn't apply to all?

Comment: If it doesn't affect in getting the `CountofApprovedPatents` and `CountofPatents` i can include the status after joining. Or i can just remove it because i won't be displaying it inside the table, what's important is to get the 2 queries.

Comment: **If** fetching `status` column **isn't important**, then you can use [union](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#unions) to join these 2 queries since number of columns and it's datatypes match.

Comment: I get this error Cardinality violation: 1222 The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns.

Comment: Yes, as aforementioned, number of columns for both queries and it's datatype should match. You can remove `status` column from your first query since you said `Or i can just remove it because i won't be displaying it inside the table`.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you edit your post and show the code you tried?

Comment: I edited my post, i also tried using union inside `$totalPatents` putting `$approvedPatents` in but i'm only getting the `CountofStatus`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use MySQL's [IF condition](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) in your raw selection of columns.

```
$results = DB::table('patents')
->select('person_id', 
          DB::raw('sum(IF(status = 2,1,0)) as CountofApprovedPatents'),
          DB::raw('count(*) as CountofPatents')
->where([
    ['date_approved', '>=', $start],
    ['date_approved', '<=', $end],
])
->groupBy('person_id')
->orderBy('status', 'desc')
->get();
```

The above `IF` condition in `sum()` adds `1` to the result if current row's `status` is `2`, else it adds `0` which effectively doesn't break the sum.

Comment: It already fetches both of `CountofApprovedPatents` and `CountofPatents` in one query. But both of them have the same `count()`. `CountofApprovedPatents` should have a lower value, i tried editing my database values to change some of the `status` as well.

Comment: @AndyStone My bad. It's actually `sum()` instead of `count()`. I fixed it.

Comment: Thank you thank you very much! It's working as intended. I can't thank you enough. Already accepted it as the answer. Have a good day @vivek_23

Comment: @AndyStone Welcome to SO. Glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

What I think you are looking for is [Unions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#unions,).

It'll allow you to specify a query and then join it with the final query.

Eg.

```
$first = DB::table('users')
            ->whereNull('first_name');

$users = DB::table('users')
            ->whereNull('last_name')
            ->union($first)
            ->get();
```

Try:

```
$approvedPatents = DB::table('patents')
->select('person_id', DB::raw('count(*) as CountofApprovedPatents, status'))
->where([
    ['status', '=', 2],
    ['date_approved', '>=', $start],
    ['date_approved', '<=', $end],
])
->groupBy('person_id')
->orderBy('status', 'desc')


$totalPatents = DB::table('patents')
->select('person_id', DB::raw('count(*) as CountofPatents'))
->where([
    ['date_approved', '>=', $start],
    ['date_approved', '<=', $end],
])
->groupBy('person_id')
->orderBy('status', 'desc')
->union($approvedPatents)
->get();
```

Otherwise you could be looking for [Joins](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#joins) - worth a look at the docs :)

**Unions:** https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#unions

**Joins:** https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#joins

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried the above code, but I'm only getting the `CountofPatents`. It didn't include `CountofApprovedPatents` in the query.